# How do i delete a github repository i created from the command line?

Tags: git

I am trying to deploy my django app on heroku, and for that I create a github repository with `git init`.
But after getting the process wrong several times, I want to start all over again. But whenever I run `git init` again, after copying the entire project folder and pasting it somewhere else, it shows this:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/Padma Jain/Desktop/blog/mysite/.git/
```

How do I delete that git repository so that after I run `git init`, it shows me something like this:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Padma Jain/Desktop/blog/mysite/.git/
```

Whenever I go to my github account, I cant see that repository anywhere. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I create a github repository with git init

That does not create a "GitHub repository", just a *local* Git repository on your PC.

All you need to do, in order to start over, is to delete the `C:/Users/Padma Jain/Desktop/blog/mysite/.git` folder

Answer (score -2):

open your repository from github then click on **Settings** menu of right corner
**scroll down** you can see **Danger Zone** and click on delete this repository

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question that whenever I open my github account, I am not able to see that repository anywhere

Comment: Samyak Jain: if you don't see it on GitHub, great. Be careful with such answers like here from Mynul. A lot of people confuse Git and GitHub :)